# How to return all Dataset by Sequel query

Tags: ruby, sequel

Rails `scope` returns `all`(`ActiveRecord::Relation`) instead of `nil`.
So that I can use method chain when `condition` is `nil`.

```
class MyClass < ApplicationRecord
  scope :my_filter, ->(condition) { where(condition: condition) if condition.present? }
end

MyClass.where(foo: 'foo').my_filter(condition).order(:date)
```

I want to implement similar functionality in Sequel, but this code doesn't work well because all in Sequel returns an Array. How can I write a functionality in Sequel similar to Rails scope?

```
class MyClass < Sequel::Model
  dataset_module do
    def my_filter(condition)
      return all if condition.nil?
      where(condition: condition) 
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `where` returns a `Dataset` I am assuming you would also like "all" to return the same object.

As you have identified `all` will return an `Array`; however you can retrieve the `Dataset` by using either `clone` or `self`

So we can just change your implementation to:

```
class MyClass < Sequel::Model
  datase_module do
    def my_filter(condition)
      return clone if condition.nil?
      where(condition: condition) 
    end
  end
end
```

Working Example: https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/SequelGemRailsScope#main.rb

**Additional Info**:

I chose `clone` because most query methods utilize this method (similar to `spawn` in `ActiveRecord`).

`Dataset#clone` looks like this

```
def clone(opts = nil || (return self))
  c = super(:freeze=>false)
  c.opts.merge!(opts)
  unless opts.each_key{|o| break if COLUMN_CHANGE_OPTS.include?(o)}
    c.clear_columns_cache
  end
  c.freeze
end
```

`clone`'s method signature shortcuts execution if no condition is passed and simply returns `self`.

As stated in the comments

> return self used above because clone is called by almost all
> other query methods, and it is the fastest approach

However the comments do also state

> This method should generally not be called directly by user code.

So you could choose to just use `return self` instead.*

<sub>*I implemented both options in my Example above to show their identical functionality plus that method signature is pretty interesting</sub>

Comment: I want to use the method with method chains, The `dataset` returns all records ignoring other query. I edited my question to make more clear what I want.

Comment: @ironsand updated my post. You were correct `dataset` will not work (and is actually not an accessible method inside the `DatasetModule`) but `clone` will result in your desired outcome.